# Why does content size of UITableView Change

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UITableView that I am loading my data in 3 blocks. I load the latest 10 records and when user pulls up using the `UIRefreshControl`, I load the preceding 10 and show the last row from the previous block. I store the previous content size right before I load the new set from database

```
previousContentSizeHeight = tableView.contentSize.height
```

and then when data comes and update my array, I use previous to calculate the new content size of table

```
let difference = tableView.contentSize.height - 
     previousContentSizeHeight - MinimumCellHeight

self.messageTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: difference), animated: false)
```

This works for the most part. It behaves correctly after the viewDidAppear when loading the first set and when loading the 2nd set, but in the third set it starts changing in content size. It gets decreased! My understanding is if I am adding data to it (not deleting anything), the content size should only grow.
I have in multiple places in my code readings of the table content size like this event:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("tableView.contentSize.height is: \(tableView.contentSize.height)")
}
```

as I am scrolling up and down, I see the number decrease and sometimes increase and decrease
Why does content size changes in size!?

NOTE: I want to stick to using the content offset. I have more luck with it than IndexPath.

**UPDATE #1**
@Sohil R. Memon: I tried your suggestion. Per screenshot, I added a print statement and as you can see the viewDidLayoutSubviews is still not executing. i tried inside the endDisplaying with self.messageTableView and just tableView
 [image]

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting the `contentSize` on every data fetch to be something like `yourDataSourceArray.count * minimumCellHeight` ?

Comment: @Rikh what if the content of the height is dynamically computed? This leads to wrong behavior

Comment: Fair enough, in that case you will have to calculate the minimum height based on constraints and use that

Answer (score 0):

Once the cell are displayed and `didEndDisplaying` is called, there are more things to process and when you scroll `cellForItem` calls again and that gives you different sizes.

In order to get the exact `contentSize` of `UITableView` once all the cells are displayed, you can get it from below method. Just write the below method in your `UIViewController` class.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    print(tableView.contentSize.height) //Exact Content Size of UITableView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer. My issue is not happening at the initial loading of the view. It works fine then. My issue is when loading 3rd block, the 3rd call to the DB to get the 3rd set. 
I added the event you mentioned but it is not getting called when the table content changes or when the didEndDisplaying event is triggered.

Comment: "Tells the delegate that the specified cell was removed from the table." that's in the documentation. You are using it here in a wrong context.

Comment: Yes, no doubt on documentation and the context is also correct, because when the cells are properly arranged and removed from the `UITableView`, you will get the exact `contentSize` of it! Let me know, if you have more confusion!